# Show block on nodes the user can edit?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

What block visibility PHP snippet would show a block only on node pages that the loged-in user can edit? The user may not own the node. In my case, I want to show the Content Complete block to people who can actually populate missing fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check for node_access("update", $node) (more on http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_access/6)


  `//first check whether it is a node page
  if(arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))){
    //load $node object
    $node = node_load(arg(1))
    //check for node update access
    if (node_access("update", $node)){
      return TRUE;
    }
  }`

Comment: +1 - a straight solution. I'd replace the if clause with a `return node_access("update", $node)`, though ;)

Comment: you're right, although my code is slightly more legible. but if the user knows php, yours is the best suggestion.

Comment: just do it.
btw, remove those off topic comments and, if needed, create another question.

Answer (score 0):

Following is barraponto's solution rewritten for noobs like me and to support multiple conditions.

```
<?php
$match = FALSE;

// Show block only if user has edit privilges for the node page
// first check whether it is a node page
if(arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))){
    //load $node object
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    //check for node update access
    if (node_access("update", $node)){
        $match = TRUE;
    }
}

return $match;
?>
```